A guy finds his missing wife's ring in a pawn shop
He is on his honeymoon I believe, and he sees this ring at a pawn shop and is obsessed with finding how it got there, and then it leads him to his wife that went missing years earlier at this farmhouse with other women in cages that refer to their captor as "daddy" I believe.
I only saw this part of the movie, I set it up to DVR and lost power, I really want to see the rest of this movie, I have no clue which actors are in it. American film, in English. No idea when it was made, it was on IFC 2-3 years ago when I saw this small part of the movie.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give?

You described one of the stories in Pawn Shop Chronicles from 2013 (with Paul Walker, Elijah Wood and many others) in which a man finds his missing wife's ring in a pawn shop and tracks her down to a kidnapper who keeps women in cages behind his farmhouse. Here's the trailer:




Thanks, I had no idea Paul Walker was in this, but I only saw that one scene that I described, which was pretty f***ed up!!
